# Resizing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel

I have a question about resizing a `JPanel`.

I  have a `JSlider`, which resize a `JPanel` dynamycly. When i change the value `Height()` of `JPanel`, size of panel decreases or increases, from top to down, effect as the `curtain`, but when I change a value `Width()`,  it does not effect `curtain`, Panel resizes from Center, and decreases or increases in both sides at the same time.

Dear experts, tell please how can I resize a Panel width from left to right, or backward?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class Swipe extends JFrame {

    static JPanel panel = null;
    static JPanel panel2 = null;
    static JPanel panel3 = null;
    static JLabel label1 = null;
    static JLabel label2 = null;
    static JSlider slider = null;
    static JToolBar bar = null;
    ImageIcon img;

    public Swipe(ImageIcon img1, ImageIcon img2) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        bar = new JToolBar();
        bar.add(slider(img1));
        frame.add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setLayout(null);
        label1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(img2.getIconWidth(), img2.getIconHeight()));
        label1.setIcon(img1);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label1, new GridBagConstraints());

        label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img2.getIconWidth(), img2.getIconHeight() + 20));
        label2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(img2.getIconWidth(), img2.getIconHeight()));
        label2.setIcon(img2);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label2.add(panel);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.setSize(img2.getIconWidth() + 50, img2.getIconHeight() + 50);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public JSlider slider(final ImageIcon im) {
        slider = new JSlider();
        slider.setMaximum(im.getIconHeight());
        slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int value = slider.getValue();
                //panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(im.getIconWidth(),value));
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(value, im.getIconHeight()));
                panel.repaint();
                panel.updateUI();
            }
        });
        return slider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `updateUI`, it has nothing to do with invalidating or repainting the UI, but notifying changes about the look and feel. Oh, and the use of `static` variables in this context is not a good idea ;)

Comment: Try to set the same panel size to frame as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Thanks for your notes, i'm newer in java programming, in the future i will write a cleaner code. Can you tell me please, why in this context it's not good to use a static vars.

Comment: The potentional is that you can create more then one instance of `Swipe`, but all instances of the class will share the same `static` references, meaning if one class changes one of the values, all the other instances will share the change, this means if you try and interact with any of the components, you won't know exactly which instance (`Swipe`) is actually using

Answer (score 1):

While it is surely possible to do your way, it is much simpler and easier to use [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) to achieve I think the comparable goal:

```
new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, 
  componentOnLeft, Component componentOnRight);
```

`JSplitPane` also has the [setDividerLocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setDividerLocation%28double%29) methods (one absolute, one proportional) if you need to resize the two components programmatically.